# Bluej packaging a project

Tags: java, executable-jar, bluej

Can some tell me how/if I can convert a bluej project into a packaged jar that can be run by clicking on it? I have to convert a big project I'm working on in BlueJ into a packaged jar and I'm really not sure how to go about that. Thanks and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Found this online, does it work for you? http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/300s05/bluej.packages.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Create Jar File and then choose your main class. If you're making a Swing (GUI) application, this is the class which creates your main JFrame. If this is not a GUI application, then this is whichever class makes the program start i.e. the controller class. Remember, if you are not making a GUI application and are only using `System.out.println();` then you need to run it through your terminal application (command prompt for Windows and terminal for OSX/Linux).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do GUI based apps need to be run from the terminal?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I think you might have misunderstood my answer :P I actually said the opposite i.e. if it's a GUI based application, you can simply double click it. Otherwise, you'll need to run it via the terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the stuff mentioned already, you'll need to run the java launcher with the -jar flag, e.g.

`java -jar myProgram.jar`

This tells the launcher it's dealing with an archive/whole app and not just a class.